# How can I assign gulp node module in gradle-gulp-plugin?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

Default location of node modules is the 'node_modules' directory in root of the project. But I changed the directory into the 'grunt' folder where located in second depth of root directory. So I have to let the plugin know the location of node_modules that has gulp module. If I do, the plugin will execute to build.

How can I achieve this? I am afraid that the plugin is not popular right now and there is nobody who knows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hardcoded, you cannot change that directory.  Look in the plugin source - https://github.com/srs/gradle-grunt-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/moowork/gradle/grunt/GruntTask.groovy

```
private final static String GRUNT_SCRIPT = 'node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt';
```

If you really want in that directory, maybe create your own plugin and extend the current gradle-grunt plugin or modify and submit pull request.

Comment: OMG. I really hoped the plugin gave a freedom the variable. OK. I will change my node module directory to the standard. thanks.!!

Comment: it is also impossible to change the gulpfile.js?